# Specify date to a given date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Is there any possibility to specify minDate/maxDate for a jqueryUI datepicker as a relative date to a given date, not today?

If I specify a relative date, it is relative to today. Can I do something like "01.01.2012 -3y" meaning three years before Jan 1st 2012? And most importantly, can I do it in one string?

As far as I can see from jqueryUI docs is not possible, but just wanted to check.

Comment: Can you be more explicit? Can you show what you've done?

Comment: Let's say that I want to set the maxDate of a datepicker to a year from now - then I will put maxDate: "+1y".

What if I want to set it a year from Jan 1st 2013? Can I specify then something like maxDate: "01/01/2013 +1y"?

I don't specify directly "01/01/2014", because that date is concatenated from another string.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can in one line but you can compute the maxDate first and then give it to the datepicker:

```
function addYearsDate(dateText, years) {
    var curDate = new Date(Date.parse(dateText));
    var nextDate = new Date();
    nextDate.setYear(curDate.getFullYear() + years);
    var curDay = nextDate.getDate();
    var curMonth = nextDate.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
    var curYear = nextDate.getFullYear();
    return curYear + "/" + curMonth + "/" + curDay;​
}

var newDate = addYearsDate("2012/12/8", 3); // will ouput "2015/12/8"
```

EDIT: As mentionned in another answer you can returned directly the nextDate object from the function instead of formatting as datepicker() can handle an object

Comment: Instead of years parameter, can you specify a string, something like addDate("2012/12/8", "+3y +3m") ?

Comment: No I don't think you can easyly, you'd have to modify the function to take 3 parameters : number of days, months and years to add

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the [jQuery documentation](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max) you could just pass a Date object,

```
minDate: new Date(2009, 1 - 1, 1)
maxDate: new Date(2009, 12 - 1, 31)
```

instead of just an offset `"-1M"`.